# Gatsby Styled Components plugin: window is not defined

Tags: gatsby, styled-components, sanity

I'm getting the following error inside my Gatsby with Sanity app on running `npm run build`:

```
 WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined (from plugin: gatsby-plugi
  n-styled-components)
```

Seems to be that the external package `gatsby-plugin-styled-components` is using `window` somewhere.I've tried replacing by a dummy module as described here https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules except my styled-components does not work then so it is not a solution.

Perhaps I'm using styled component techniques where are not supported? I've looked at different gatsby/styled components example repo's and cannot find the difference.

You can find the repo here: https://github.com/sanderdebr/sanity-gatsby-portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your project or the `gatsby-plugin-styled-components` is using somewhere styled-components@5.2.2 which is a broken version using `window`.

The issue has been tracked on SC Github: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3444

I recommend you to update to styled-components@5.2.3